# How MSSql covering indexes should be configured in Oracle Sql Developer (Data Modeller) ver 4.1.5.21

Tags: configuration, oracle-sqldeveloper, data-modeling, covering-index

Could someone please help me on how to configure a Covering Index (INCLUDE option) in Oracle Sql Developer (Data Modeller) ver 4.1.5.21.
I could find only the option to create a normal index or to use 'index expression' where we can directly put the index script.

The goal is to use the tool itself to build the covered index so that, for example, if we make a change in a column name this is reflected automatically in the index when creating the ddl.

Thanks
Moinak Roy

Comment: after trying for about 15 minutes, I'm pretty sure we don't support the INCLUDE clause when designing SQL Server indexes

Comment: Thanks Jeff...Your confirmation reassured my findings and could close the issue.